# PHP post and get value to a jQuery box page, refresh page as `msnbc.com`

Tags: php, jquery, post, hash

Finally, I find some article in http://code.google.com/intl/en/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html msnbc use this method. Thanks for all the friends.

Thanks for your all help. I will study it for myself :-}

Today, I updated my question again, remove all of my code. Maybe my thinking all wrong.

I want make a products show page.

One is `index.php`, another is `search.php` (as a jquery box page). `index.php` has some products catagory lists; each click on product catagory item will pass each value to `search.php`. `search.php` will create a mysql query and view products details. It(`search.php`) also has a search box.(`search.php` can turn a page to show multiple products; the search result looks similar to a jQuery gallery...).

I need to do any thing in `search.php` but without refreshing `index.php`.

I tried many method while I was thinking: Make search.php as an iframe (but can not judge search.php height when it turn page and index.php without refresh); use jquery ajax/json pass value from index.php to search.php, then get back all page's value to index.php. (still met some url rule trouble. php depend on url pass values in `search.php`, but if the value change, the two page will refresh all. )

so. I think, ask, find, try...
Accidental, I find a site like my request.

[in this url, change search word after %3D, only the box page refresh](http://powerwall.msnbc.msn.com/#!wallState=0__/politics/search?searchTerm=usa)

[in this url, change search word after = the page will refresh](http://powerwall.msnbc.msn.com/politics/search?searchTerm=usa)

I found somthing in its source code, is this the key rules?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var fastReplace = function() {
    var href = document.location.href;
    var siteUrl = window.location.port ? window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname +':'+window.location.port : window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname;
    var delimiter = href.indexOf('#!') !== -1 ? '#!wallState=' : '#wallState=';

    var pieces = href.split(delimiter);
    if ( pieces[1] ) {
        var pieces2 = pieces[1].split('__');
        if ( pieces2[1] && pieces2[1].length > 1) {
            window.location.replace( unescape(pieces2[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")));
        }
    }
}();
</script>
```

If so. in my condition. one page is index.php. another is search.php.
How to use js make a search url like

`index.php#search.php?word=XXX&page=XXX`

then how to pass value from one to another and avoid refreshing index.php?

Still waiting for help, waiting for some simple working code, only `js, pass value get value`.

Thanks to all.

Comment: i didn't really got it. Do you want to rewrite the url in the addressbar? everything behind the hash-mark (#) can only be seen by the client ...

Comment: @helle, do you think this is just an url rewrite? I am not care about this. I am care about the effection. pls go to `http://powerwall.msnbc.msn.com/`, click each photo, open a box page. do anything in the box page, try to search something in bing on the top. the main page will not refresh, but the box page can turn page, change url. How to do that? this is simlilar as I need. do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: technically, the jquery plugin is grabbing whatever is after wallState there, its not actually post or get as there is no request to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you really want to do something like here: http://powerwall.msnbc.msn.com/

I guess they are using a combination of ajax-requests and something like this: http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

make shure that the navigation (all links, etc.) in the box works via ajax - check all the links and give them new functionality by js. you can write some function which requests the href url via ajax and then replace the content of your box. ...

```
function change_box_links(output_area){
    output_area.find('a').each(function(){
        $(this).bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(data){
                    output_area.html(data);
                    //update url in addressbar
                    change_box_links(output_area);
                }
            });

        });
    });
}
```

it is upgradeable but shell show the main idea...

**addendum**[2011-05-15]

Get away from thinking you will have two files, that can handle some many "boxes". i mean you can do this but it's worth it.

but to be able to set up your templates like normal html page you could use the above script to parse the ajax requested html pages.

build your html-pages for

- viewing the content,
- viewing the search result
- , etc.

on your main page you have to provide some "box" where you can display what u need. i recommand a `div`:

`<div id="yourbox"></div>`

your main page has buttons to display that box with different content, like in the example page you have showed us. if you click one of those a JS will create an ajax call to the desired page:

*(here with jquery)*

```
$('#showsearch_button').bind('click', function(){showsearch();});

function show_search() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search.php',
        success: function(data){
            var output_area = $('#yourbox');
            output_area.html(data);
            $.address.hash('search');
            change_box_links(output_area);
         }
    });
});
```

for other buttons you will have similar functions.
the first function (see above) provides that the requested box-content can be written as a normal html page (so you can call it as stand-alone as well). here is the update of it where it also provides the hashtag url changes:

*jquery and requireing the [history-plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/)*

```
function change_box_links(output_area){
    output_area.find('a').each(function(){
        $(this).bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(data){
                    output_area.html(data);
                    var name = url.replace('/\.php/','');
                    $.address.hash(name);
                    change_box_links(output_area);
                }
            });

        });
    });
}
```

and you will need some kind of this function, which will bind the back and forward buttons of your browser:

```
$.address.change(function(event) {
    var name = $.address.hash();
    switch(name){
        case 'search': show_search(); break;
        default: alert("page not found: "+name);
    }
});
```

the above code should give an idea of how you can solve your problem. you will have to be very consequnt with filenames if you just copy and past this. again: it is improveable but shell show you the trick ;-)

Comment: @helle, so how to deal in `search.php`? if search more in `search.php`, is it nessassery pass search value depend on url? so both 2 pages will refresh. Thanks.

Comment: if you do the ajax call you can pass post and get variables. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @helle, I am not sure how to write ajax in this two page, so that search anything in `search.php` and `index.php` without refresh. I have tried `jqeury.post`, `jquery.json` and even `jquery.load`(load search.php in a div of index.php). But when I do other thing in `search.php`(search result pagination), the two page will refresh. So, can you give me some simple worked code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you will have to transform all your stuff into ajax calls. I don't see any other way...

Comment: @helle, it is a difficult question. I am weak in pure ajax. Just learn little jquery.ajax. so can instruct me further more? Thanks again.

Comment: @helle, well friend, I still not work it out with ajax. (may be ajax can. but as my weak knowledge. in the 3 answers, only your method maybe. so I give the bounty to u). I find some article in `http://code.google.com/intl/en/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html` msnbc use something here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I have read your problem, though I can not write complete code for you (lack of time ) So I can suggest you to what to do for your best practice

use `dataType ='json'` in **jQuery.ajax** function and
 write [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on **B.php**
 and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on **A.php** or [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

**Alternate:**

Read 
[jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: @diEcho, too many thanks. I have read the tutorial and tried use json pass data. But still have some trouble. When I search or turn page in page B, the page A also refresh. I find somepage like what I want. See my update question part. I notice its url rule: page b write afte an `url anchor`, so that turn page B not refresh page A. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @diEcho, I have made an upvote 2 days ago. And if u could help me work out this problem, I will also pleasure give 200 bounties to u. But there have a problem. my `page b` has a mysql search, if I paste code to `ideone.com` or `codepad.org`, how to connect to a database? If not it is hard to examine. Thanks again.

Comment: no need of connection. i'll just see your code.. watever u r getting mysql make an array on b.php.that's it :)

Comment: i'll check it out( currently i m too busy) and help u

Comment: @diEcho, no problem. u r kindly.

Comment: @yuli, i didn't see your update part and also there is no code for page A and page B, please provide me . please explain step by step that what is currently happening and what u exact want.

Comment: @diEcho， the code in `http://codepad.org/1rz0s8ET` and `http://codepad.org/ED3OrLVb`, but I think my method is wrong. I find a site simlilar as I need: `http://powerwall.msnbc.msn.com/`
so I updated my questions. try in msnbc. you can click each photo, open a box page. then search anything with bing in the box page, just refresh the box page, but not refresh the main page. this is similar as I need. Maybe u can do in your way, not follow my fault. and help me reach this effection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure that i fully understood what you want, but correct me if i didnt,

i think u need something like a dropdown that once the user select one item some div inside ur page show the result of another page result..

if so u can do it with jquery .load() and here is an example (no need for json)

**Step 1:**

**Index.php**

```
<p>
        brand:<select id=jquerybrand>$jquerybrands</select><br />
        Model:<select id=jquerycars></select><br />
</p>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#jquerybrand').change(function(){
var value=$(this).value;
var url='api/quick.php?'+this.id+'='+this.value+' option';
$('#jquerycars').load(url);
});
});
</script>
```

This will simply show 2 dowpdown boxs (can be text or anything u like). and will add a listener to any change in value. once changed it will submit the id of the field and the new value to api/quick.php , then quick.php responce will be loaded into #jquerycars dropdown.

**Step 2 quick.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['jquerybrand'])){
$jquerycars="";
require_once("../lib/database.php");
$sql_db = new database();
$l=$sql_db->Item_in_table("car","sheet1","WHERE `brand`='$jquerybrand';");
foreach($l as $l)$jquerycars .="<option>$l</option>";
echo $jquerycars;//response that will replace the old #jquerycars
}
```

this will confirm that this is a request to get the query result only, then it will do the query and echo the results.
now once the results come back it will replace the old  :)

hope it helps :).

Comment: @Momen M El Zalabany, thanks your reply. Sorry for I can not explain my quetion clearly in english. so this make me several days, finally I find some site like my request. `http://powerwall.msnbc.msn.com/`. you can try in there. (in the main page, he has many pictures, but I replace into many word links). `click each link`, open a box page.(may be in this step he use statics page, but I use a mysql query, query out all this kind of products) `Then make anything in box page, the main page without refresh`. The next fuction, we both are similar. box page also have a search function. see his top.

Comment: well powerwall.msnbc is working exactly as i showed u..

it load content once clicked into hidden div and then show it, and animate move of other photos .. i can show u complete code if u accept this as a solution

Comment: http://www.pndmasr.com/find.php here is an example i wrote on this car website (still underconstruction but u can see concept.)

Comment: @Momen M El Zalabany, thanks, I see your demos. I have noticed, but your search will still refresh all the page. but `msnbc` not, try the bing search at top. And I need the effection like `msnbc`.

Comment: @Momen M El Zalabany, u r so great. Is this site yours? click right ads for a support :)

Comment: yeap its mine but still need extensive design work :). thank for the clicks :D,
if u click the car name it will load car info in the right side without refresh, if u wana i can customize code for ya to do same as msn. web

Comment: @Momen M El Zalabany, yes I want a effection like bing search. Thanks for your extensive design work :)